# How to find out the reason for failed signing in, when ASP.NET Core fails to sign in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity to manage users. And I get this response when I'm trying to sign-in a user:

```
{
    type: "Error",
    message: "Not logged in",
    data: {
        succeeded: false,
        isLockedOut: false,
        isNotAllowed: false,
        requiresTwoFactor: false
    }
}
```

As you can see, user is not logged in, and no other reason is **true**.

What should I do now to find out "why" user has not logged in? How to find the error here?

The method I'm using is `PasswordSignInAsync` and the result it returns is `SignInResult` and it does not have a field for the error description.

Comment: Hi @tayebepourmand, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

> The method I'm using is PasswordSignInAsync and the result it returns is SignInResult and it does not have a field for the error description.

To troubleshoot the issue, you can refer to the following code snippet to check if user is existing/registered, then check if the given password is valid for the specified user.

```
//check if user is existing 
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email); //or .FindByNameAsync(username_here)


//check if pwd is valid
var pwd_is_valid = _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

And, you can try to debug your code and check if any useful logs are written to output window.

[image]

Besides, you can try to register a new user and login with that new user's account to check if it can work well.